# Mongo query with group

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo Collection that has below structure in which a transactionID can have multiple page numbers.

Now I want to do this :

For each day (as per timestamp attr), I want to
- return list of transactionIDs, for which `processed=False` for all pages numbers.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d11f35a0c4fd2df3558cf80"),
    "DB" : "test1",
    "sid" : 8732,
    "filetype" : "csv",
    "processed" : "False",
    "pagesNo" : 3,
    "timestamp" : 1599068960,
    "transactionID" : 837423be237e2e
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d11f35a0c4fd2df3558cf80"),
    "DB" : "test1",
    "sid" : 8732,
    "filetype" : "csv",
    "processed" : "False",
    "pagesNo" : 4,
    "timestamp" : 1599068960,
    "transactionID" : 837423be237e2e
}
```

Expected output:

```
 {
   "transacionID" : "837423be237e2e",
   "sid" : "8732"
   "datetime" : "2020-09-02"
   }
```

I have reached upto here, hwere I am able to group the results as per transactionID

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$transactionID",
            "total": { "$sum": 1 },
            "sid": { "$first": "$sid"}
        }
    }, 
    
];
    
    
db.items.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output, we need to use UNIX timestamp

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      processed: "False"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$transactionID",
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "sid": {
        "$first": "$sid"
      },
      date: {
        $first: {
          $toDate: {
            $multiply: [
              "$timestamp",
              1000
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WuQW8Cyij87)**

Comment: not sure...why but it says Nameerror `processed is not defined` but the field is their. I tried with $processed, but same error

Comment: @prashantitis Try enclosing `processed` in double quotes and test it again.

Comment: @prashantitis If the answer helps you, please click on tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question